# How to get the output of an Object function as Variable

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.6

I am new to this and trying pass the output of this function as a string to the tweepy update method ( To post as a statue )

```
              def hello():
                  name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
               if name:
                  print ("Hello " + str(name))
               else:
                 print("Hello World") 
                 return 

                 hello()
```

The Issue here is Tweepy's  " api.update_status ( status ) " would only accept a string or a variable encasing a string. Using a Function call prints out errors.

How Do I go about this simple process?

I have tried to pass the function output  as a variable

```
             test = hello()
```

but this prints out errors to twitter.

```
              ...
              api.update_status (test)
```

Comment: I am more concern about the output of the function call. How do I post this on Twitter  through tweepy?

Comment: you have to use `return "Hello World"` instead of `print("Hello World")`. The same with other `print()`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `input()` always gives string so you don't need `str()`

Answer (score 1):

Your function return a None object, you function should return a string like 
@furas mentioned above.

try this:

```
def hello():
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name:
        return "Hello " + name
    else:
        return "Hello World"


hello()
```

and you still pass a function call to the api

```
api.update_status(hello())
```